# SQL Server 2017 peer-to-peer Replication problem after adding new column

Tags: replication, sql-server-2017

Originally I have a DB config p2p replication data between 2 SQL Server 2017

`Sp_MSupd_XXX` has a parameter

```
@bitmap binary(21)
```

System table `Conflict_XXX` column

```
 __$update_bitmap varbinary(21)
```

Everything works fine.

But after I add a new column in table `XXX` the SQL replication function re-generates the `sp_MSupd_XXX` with

```
@bitmap binary(22)
```

but table `Conflict_XXX` still has length 21:

```
__$update_bitmap varbinary(21)
```

When replication data conflict occurs `sp_MSupd_XXX` tries to insert into `Conflict_XXX` and then SQL raises an error

> String would be truncated

Then it stop replicating data.

Can I alter the system column `__$update_bitmap` to `varbinary(22)` by hand? Or can I regenerate `sp_MSupd` and conflict log table without dropping and adding articles?

Sorry for my poor English.

I try to drop and add article on testing server, it works. But I don't want to loss replication transaction.